# C# Get Json Response into an Array

Tags: c#, json

Through webrequest I am getting response text which is in Json I use Newtonsoft.Json to parse. I created classes with the help of examples from stackoverflow website but couldn't figure out how to loop whole response into an array or datatable/dataview.

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
public class Link
        {
            public string rel { get; set; }
            public string href { get; set; }
        }

        public class Naeringskode1
        {
            public string kode { get; set; }
            public string beskrivelse { get; set; }
        }

        public class Postadresse
        {
            public string adresse { get; set; }
            public string postnummer { get; set; }
            public string poststed { get; set; }
            public string kommunenummer { get; set; }
            public string kommune { get; set; }
            public string landkode { get; set; }
            public string land { get; set; }
        }

        public class Beliggenhetsadresse
        {
            public string adresse { get; set; }
            public string postnummer { get; set; }
            public string poststed { get; set; }
            public string kommunenummer { get; set; }
            public string kommune { get; set; }
            public string landkode { get; set; }
            public string land { get; set; }
        }

        public class Link2
        {
            public string rel { get; set; }
            public string href { get; set; }
        }

        public class Naeringskode2
        {
            public string kode { get; set; }
            public string beskrivelse { get; set; }
        }

        public class Datum
        {
            public int organisasjonsnummer { get; set; }
            public string navn { get; set; }
            public string organisasjonsform { get; set; }
            public string registreringsdatoEnhetsregisteret { get; set; }
            public string registrertIMvaregisteret { get; set; }
            public int antallAnsatte { get; set; }
            public Naeringskode1 naeringskode1 { get; set; }
            public Postadresse postadresse { get; set; }
            public Beliggenhetsadresse beliggenhetsadresse { get; set; }
            public int overordnetEnhet { get; set; }
            public List<Link2> links { get; set; }
            public string hjemmeside { get; set; }
            public Naeringskode2 naeringskode2 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Page
        {
            public int size { get; set; }
            public int page { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Link> links { get; set; }
            public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
            public Page page { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: you want the json into the structure you provided above?

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm

Comment: @Ric I never worked with json, Would like for ex: adresse,postnummer,poststed as columns and data under those columns. If all columns and data convert into array so that I can view that data into datagridview.

Comment: @Ric This is the way I get response ' WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd(); '

Comment: Something like this (tweak as you need) `var result = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(responseFromServer);`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I read into an array so that I can view it into datagridview?

Comment: Can anyone help me here. Please.